# Drupal 8 - contact page and referencing forms

Tags: forms, drupal-8

I've created a content-type - called contact -- that is similar to a basic page - but I want to give it the ability to add forms to the page.

So I want to reference the "contact/feedback" form - and have it appear under the body of the "contact" page. I am unsure though how to setup the content-type to allow the user to reference the contact form entity - and to display it as its raw form on that page.

--

Or if this is the wrong approach - how would I create and manage a block of html/content above the contact/feedback form generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really basic and you should easily be able to find an answer if you spend some time researching.

The easiest, and imo standard, way to do this, is by adding the form block to the contact content type.
Structure => Block Layout

Comment: That's a good idea -- but I really want the form be a block - in that respect.

Comment: If you're using webforms, which is standard in D8 I think? Your form is already a block and you add it to content types this way.

Comment: I will install that module - I had extended the contact form that is there by default

Comment: The standard contact form should be a block too? We always use webforms though, so could be wrong ...

Comment: No its a good call man - that solved my problem - its been a while since I did a drupal site -- been on react these days. Yes the webform road was a very good suggestion. I had forgotten.